# My app java EE cannot get connection with my Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am training to make my first java EE app.
When I try to connect my app with the servlet it keeps conneting with the default page *index.html* (eclipse) or *index.jps* (intellij).

I really need help to make the server recognize the new servlet.

**my web.xml file:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ws.servlets</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hellow</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is `com.ws.servlets` the name of the servlet class? And what exactly do you mean by "i tried to connect my app with the servltet"?

Comment: my servlet in the package com.ws.servlets 
i tried to connect my app with the servltet : when i try to run my app with tomcat server

Comment: in the browser, what is the URL that you try to connect?

Comment: the name of the project is test    i try to connect http://localhost:8086/test/hellow
or http://localhost:8086/test/Test/hellow

Comment: localhost:8086/test/hellow  is the right URL. If it is possible, can you send the hole project to test it locally?

Comment: i ran the server and i get error 404
how can i sent the hole project?

Comment: the project is nothing but a simple new project with Test servlet

Comment: By default Tomcat listens on port 8080.  Did you try http://localhost:8080/test/hellow?

Comment: you are right, but i changed it because the port 8080 didn't work with me, and i got error with 8080